# Find role id by name discord rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now I'm working on a command for my discord bot where I create a role named after a user, and then automatically assign it to that user. The only problem I'm running into is trying to assign the role *without knowing its id yet* to the person mentioned.
My command so far:

```
@client.command(aliases = ["cmr", "CMR"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def creatememberrole(ctx, *, member:discord.Member):
    author = ctx.message.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    print(author.display_name)
    await guild.create_role(name=str(member.display_name))
    await member.add_roles()
          #need help here ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It can be done by `utils.get` easily, no need of for loop**

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=member.display_name)
await member.add_roles(role)
```

**In your case there is no need of any for loop/utils.get, just assign the `create_role()` method to a variable and use that variable**

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["cmr", "CMR"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def creatememberrole(ctx, *, member:discord.Member):
    author = ctx.message.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    print(author.display_name)
    role = await guild.create_role(name=str(member.display_name))
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Thanks! The for loop from before did make it a bit more complicated

Comment: happy to help anytime!

Answer (score 1):

You could go trough the list of all the roles, and find the role you created and assign this role. Here's an example:

```
for role in message.channel.guild.roles:
    if role.name == str(member.display_name):
        await member.add_roles(role)
```